# Doctrine: How make 'data-load' and remove index table without rebuild the DB

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

My question is about `data-load` command.

When I made more `data-load` commands, without rebuild the tables, the ID index from the table is kept ans the first line of table don't begin with ID 1. It's possible with `data-load` command to insert the data from fixtures and the id for the first line of table to be 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. In fact, `data-load` delete all entries from your database and then load them again. So the autoincrement column aren't resetted (since it performs a `DELETE` and not a `TRUNCATE`).

What you can do is before launching `data-load`, do a [`TRUNCATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/truncate-table.html) on your table. So *any `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is reset to its start value*.

Otherwise, you can use `--and-load` option from `doctrine:build`:

```
./symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load
```

It will re-generate *all classes and SQL files and rebuilt the database* then *load data from the project and plugin `data/fixtures/` directories*.

This way, every thing will be fresh, and id resetted.

Comment: Thanck you for your answer!
THe problem is that in my database exists more tables wich are related to different modules in one application. The operation 'build' generates all tables, models,etc...It's not ok for my because I want to generate certain tables, 3 of 10 for example, and insert the fixture data into these tables. In the same time, the autoincrement column must be resetted.

Comment: Sorry, Because I'am new on this site, I can't post more questions, only comments